# PHP - Delete file after upload

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload

I've developed a small tool that allows a users upload a HTML file. Once uploaded, I run an Ajax request which gets the content of that HTML file and outputs it to a textarea.

**PHP:**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($src, $dest . $uploadfile)) 
{       
    echo $uploadfile;   
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error Uploading file";
}
```

**Ajax:**

```
$.get( "uploads/" + response, function(data) {
    $('#output').text(data);                                    
});
```

Everything is working so far.

Now what I want to do is delete that file once the content has been outputted to the textarea. I'm aware I could create a cron job to execute a script every X amount of minutes, however I would rather do it there and then.

I tried using the following, but naturally this deletes the file before the Ajax request is executed.

```
if (move_uploaded_file($src, $dest . $uploadfile)) 
{       
    echo $uploadfile;   

    if($delete) {  // $delete is a boolean argument for the function        
        unlink($dest . $uploadfile);
    }
}
```

So how would I go about deleting the file once the content has been retrieved? Would I create another Ajax request to execute a delete function once the first request is complete? Or is there a way I can do this all at once?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here: `but naturally this deletes the file before the Ajax request is executed`. All you need to do is read the file and echo its contents before you unlink it.

Comment: @jeroen - Well I'm currently echoing the name using `echo $uploadfile;` which the Ajax request uses to get the file contents from. I've tried to delete the file as shown in the code above but it's deleting the file before the content is outputted to the textarea.

Comment: Where are you reading the file and which script is the one you are showing, is that the `"uploads/" + response` script?

Comment: Two options:
1. On file upload - do the following
   a. script echos file contents
   b. script deletes file
   c. client populates text area
2. On file upload
   a. script echos file name
   b. client ajax calls script
   c. script echos contents
   d. script deletes file
   e. client populates text area
Agreed with @jeroen that this should all be done with the initial file upload.

Comment: @jeroen - `response` is the name of the file so the jQuery Ajax request is `get`ing the content from `uploads/text.html` (example). I'm not using PHP `get_file_contents` function if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: Wow, that would (potentially...) allow your users to run code on your server... I would definitely not do it like that but instead direct to a script that only reads and outputs the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your ajax request to a php file, that echos the content then deletes the file:

```
//ajax
$.get( "/get-file.php?file=uploads/" + response, function(data) {
    $('#output').text(data);                                    
});
```

.

```
//get-file.php
$file=$_GET['file'];
echo file_get_contents($file);
unlink($file);
```

Note that there are some security issues related to reading a user-submitted filename (they could pass in the filepath of a secure file, e.g. "passwords.php").

Better would be to store and retrieve the value from SESSION:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($src, $dest . $uploadfile)) 
{       
    $_SESSION['uploadedfile']=$dest . $uploadfile;
    echo 'success';//the return is no longer used   
} 
else 
{
    echo "Error Uploading file";
}

//ajax
$.get( "/get-file.php, function(data) {
    $('#output').text(data);                                    
});
```

.

```
//get-file.php
$file=$_SESSION['uploadedfile'];
echo file_get_contents($file);
unlink($file);
```

Comment: Something like that although I would definitely do some validation on the file name.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try. @jeroen I already have validation on all files. The names are made *safe* before anything is done. Thanks for the above comments too.

Comment: @Lodder Hard to tell when seeing only a very small part of the code so I thought I'd mention it :-)